# LED resistor basic wiring

Tags: voltage, led, current, resistors, brightness

I am looking for a single **bright** LED light. I'm using:

- a red 5 mm LED
- a 5 V, 2.5 A AC adapter
- a 1 Ω resistor

It works, but doesn't seem very bright.

Am I correct or completely wrong?  What is the best color LED and resistor to optimize output using the 5 V power supply?

[image]

Comment: what does `optimize output` mean? ... read the datasheet for the LED ... there should be some graphs that show the relation between current and luminosity

Comment: One ohm is much too small. Can you draw out how you've wired it up?

Comment: The LED is most likely broken already. You need much larger resistance than 1 ohms to do this. And some data about the LED how much current it is rated for. Assumption is 20mA unless there is some evidence it can take more.

Comment: Data sheet, data sheet etc...

Comment: 1 ohm resistor is a value so low that, in that circuit, it could burn the LED. Are you sure that this resistor is 1 ohm? Isn't it 1 K ohm? Are you able to read resistor's color code? What are the color bands in the resistor?

Comment: Your wiring diagram looks good. Make sure the ground side of your power supply connects to the cathode of the LED, which is denoted by a flat edge in the plastic. The other lead goes to a resistor in the 100-500 ohm range and then to the 5V.

Answer (score 3):

For calculating the appropriate resistor, you need to find out the *forward voltage drop* of the LED, and its *forward current rating*.

These numbers are in the datasheet of the LED.

Different colours require different voltages, and Extra Bright LEDs may have different voltages and currents specified than their dimmer cousins.

**A calculation example:**

A typical red LED has a forward voltage drop of about 1.8 V.

You have a 5 V power supply.

Somehow, the difference, 5 - 1.8 = 3.2 V, needs to be dropped in a resistor in series with the LED, or the voltage across the LED will be too high, which can damage or destroy it.

Assuming a current through the LED (and therefore the resistor) of 20 mA (not an uncommon value), the resistor must be, using Ohm's law:

\$R = \large{V \over I} = \large{3.2\ \mathrm{V} \over 0.020\ \mathrm{A}} = \normalsize 160\ \Omega\$.

For 10 mA, that would be 320 Ω.

Anyway: the value of your resistor is much too low, and you have probably fried your LED, which would explain why it doesn't look all that bright.

As for colours: the human eye is most sensitive to a yellowish-green, but you can buy many colours of LEDs of various power ratings. Some require higher voltages than 5 V, though, because several LED chips are used.